# How to use RegEx to mask valid credit cards AND masked cards

Tags: regex

I have regex masks in place to validate the cards I want but we are starting to using payment profiles with our credit card vendor and I want to allow partially masked cards in the fields as well but can't figure it out.

So for example; I want to allow;

```
4111123412341234
```

and

```
XXXXXXXXXXXX1234
```

The last 4 digits will be the last four digits of the credit card which comes from our credit card processor. For the above example, my card mask 1 is `^4\d{0,15}` and I need to figure out how to modify to allow the XXXXXXXXXXXX1234 as well;

Comment: Do you mean `^(?:4\d{0,11}|X{1,12})\d{0,4}`? Maybe even ``^(?:4\d{0,11}|X{1,12})\d{0,4}$`` to match whole string?

Comment: give some more examples of what should be matched and what shouldn't

Comment: why does the first digit of your credit card has to always be a 4? I have credit cards that start with 5 and 6...

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is `either 16 digits` **or** `12 X's followed by 4 digits` then what you want is:

```
^(\d{16}|X{12}\d{4})$
```

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for. This example was only for Visa cards but you're right, we do accept cards that start with other numbers but have different pattern matches for that.